# React - MUI - cannot deselect all items in multi select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working with the MUI "multiple select" / "multiple checkbox select".

**My goal**
-> Open a modal, setState some initial value, and then have full control over the select.

**My issues**
-> Currently, the initial items can be reselected, and once they are selected they cannot be unselected.

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-1efp6?file=/src/App.js) forked from a MUI issue relating to this [MUI issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16775)

**As of now ->** I have included 3 sets of state in the sandbox

```
newOptions is equal to [options[1]]

1 - value: [options[1]]  -> Success
2 - value: options.slice(0,1)  -> Success
3 - value: newOptions  -> Failure
```

By un-commenting the different states you can see the behavior described, and the items will not be removable from the multi-select.

I'm wondering if anyone can describe this behavior and the solution to it => although I have been able to find some success (using [options[x]]) however this does not support what I am doing in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16775, You can kind of fix this by using the reference of the object as the default value e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-vgyz6

When using the reference of the object, the select component by default is using the reference equality check I think, so deselection is working.

When you use the third way, "3 - value: newOptions  -> Failure", in Javascript, even the properties and values of 2 objects are identical, yet the objects themselves aren't considered equal.

```
var jangoFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

var bobaFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

// Outputs: false
console.log(bobaFett === jangoFett);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 

I'm thinking about how to use this going forward -> I'm looking to do something like
`
useEffect(() => {
  setState({value:arrayOfObjects})
}, [])
`

If I'm trying to use the select as a controlled component, I'm not sure how I can pass the information as referenced, like you have, to my useState. Although this code sandbox is the one I adapted, I'm still not entirely sure how to use this "dynamically", essentially taking what the sandbox has, however options would be from a server

Comment: I added an example to use the reference of the object.https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-j6xyr

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see a difference between the sandbox you've linked and the one I originally posted. Could you give me the line number you're talking about?
Thanks

Comment: ok. Suppose your options list is from a server, and you use setState in useEffect, we can still call it variable options. Then you may have a list for selected items, and we name it as selectedOptions. The key is that you need to populate selectedOptions by referencing each selected item to the corresponding one in variable options. https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-jbqbr